# Using Rally Excel-Addin, can I add tags when importing new userstories to Rally?

Tags: rally, excel-addins

While importing user stories with Tags column from spreadsheet, I run into issue that Tags cannot be imported.

Is there a way to do that using Rally excel-addin. The tags currently exist in Rally. Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to import Tags using the Excel Add-in.  You will need to add the Tags using the WebUI after the import. You can do this using Bulk-Edit:

- Put a Custom List app on your dashboard or a custom page and set the
  work item type to User Story.
- Set the "show" parameter at the bottom left of the results to 200
  (the maximum batch size).
- Tick the select all checkbox at the upper right.
- Click the gear icon next to any work item- this will return the Bulk
  Actions menu.
- From Bulk Actions choose "Tag...".

The Excel Add-in is currently undergoing a rewrite an this capability will, hopefully, be a part of the new version.